# Cannot find name 'cordova'. ionic 5 build android

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, typescript-typings

I use cordova exec to call a function of my local plugin,

command `ionic cordova prepare android` get me an **error**

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'cordova'.

[image]

Is folowing my function

```
    getUserData() {
    return new Promise((Resolve, Reject) => {
      this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        cordova.exec((ResponseData) => {
          this.UserData = ResponseData;
          console.log('Key chain data', ResponseData);
          Resolve(this.UserData);
        }, (err) => {
          this.UserData = null;
          console.log('Key chain data err', err);
          this.route.navigate(['/helps'], { queryParams: { Data: JSON.stringify(err) }});
          Reject(err);
        }, 'ConnectionSecurePlugin', 'getUserPass', [] );
      });

    });
  }
```

Can somebody help me please

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: show us your plugin.xml

Comment: you mean config.xml ?

Comment: in your plugin there is plugin.xml file

Comment: you think the problem comes from the plugin?

Comment: its in the way that you call the plugin

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare cordova in that service file or ts file like

```
declare var cordova:any;
```

You have to declare that just after import statements.
Because Cordova is not directly available like normal phonegap or Cordova projects

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, I declared `var cordova: any`  just after import, I no longer have the build error. but I have this error now  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'exec' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have found that works is:

```js
// @ts-ignore
cordova.exec
..
```